# SIM900A showing Starting modem test...ERROR, no modem answer. Checking IMEI...Modem's IMEI: 0

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

---

**Edit:**

Solution can be found [**HERE**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/44981/26037)

---

I am trying to interface Simcom **SIM900A** GSM *(SIM900a Mini DEV Board v3.9.2)* and I tryed interfacing it with **Arduino UNO**. I have connected as:

**Pins:**

```
SIM900A - Arduino
=================
VCC     - VDC (+5V)
GND     - GND
5VR     - Connect to Arduino TX (Pin 1)
5VT     - Connect to Arduino RX (Pin 0)
```

**Power Supply (External):**

```
5V 2A
```

**Problem**
When I upload sketch of:

```
Example > GSM > TestModem:
```

to Arduino, I got this output from **Serial Monitor**:

> Starting modem test...ERROR, no modem answer.
>
> Checking IMEI...Modem's IMEI: 0
>
> Reseting Modem... Modem is functioning properly: IMEI: 0

**Other info:**

- By supplying `5V, 2A` the `SIM900A` `Power LED` `ON` continuesly and `Signal LED` `blink with certain period of time` which mean I am okay with signal.
- I connected SIM900A and Arduino with `Male to Male` + `Female to Female` as I don't have `Male to Female` wires. I tested the wires with Multimeter and it's prefectly working.
- I tested uploading other sketches of sending sms but not successful. Note that, I have load + free sms on SIM.
- Power supply is actually Adapter *(no transformer but circuit)* with output of `5.1 Volts`

My previous post can be checked [**HERE**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44599/sim900a-mini-modem-imei-0-help-with-tx-rx-pins)

**PS:**

Yesterday just for a minute I noted: Both LEDs *(Power + Signal)*  of SIM900A were `blinking at same time`. But then by restarting it gets Okay again.

Please help. I am likely to die becuase of tension.

Comment: Some points: 1. You can't use pins 0/1 for both the GSM and your debugging at the same time. You will have to use SoftwareSerial (ugh) on another pair of pins. 2. The GSM library is for the *Arduino GSM Shield*, **not** the SIM900A.

Comment: Hello @Majenko, Thank You very much for your comments. With due respect if you allow to let me clarify before flaging my post as duplicate, despite the title being same we have different content, also by following the instructions in mentioned post I applied that but nothing happened * (actually they say you have to use different, mine is already in place) * I know rules of SO and I will never spam it with questions by bombording it with same content. I never ask, but I research before very thoroughly. Thank You.

Comment: @Majenko Thank You. **1:** As you said: I can't use `0/1` I am using `SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 10);` Still nothing happening *(I mean not sending msg)*. **2:** If I can't use *GSM Library* what should I use to make this `SIM900A Mini` work? What I want to accomplish is **Send Text Message**. Please post Answer, so that help universe solve this problem. *(As many people are facing same problem and I found no solution)*

Comment: You already asked this question at [SIM900a Mini Modem, IMEI 0, Help with TX RX pins](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44599/sim900a-mini-modem-imei-0-help-with-tx-rx-pins)  and have now indicated that the answer is found there.   **You should not have re-posted your already asked question**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree, and I apologize for my ignorance. Actually I wait for answer and every second I used to refresh my page but go no answer. For the sake of attention and more clarity I asked again with little different context. BTW the "answer there" is also mine. I give link just for ease if in case someone like me needed. Anyways Thank You very much. If anyone want to delete this post I am okay with it. I am okay with every SO rules. Once again accept apologize.

Comment: Re-posting to get extra attention is pretty much exactly what is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

---

**Note:**

Detailed Solution can be found [**Here**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/44981/26037)

---

**Excerpt:**

My Pins connections were wrong, it should not be: `0` and `1` it should be `2` & `3`

Also `SoftwareSerial.h` is not working with `SIM900A`

**Pins:**

All connections should be like this:

```
SIM900A - Arduino
=================
VCC     - VDC (+5V)
GND     - GND
5VR     - Connect to Arduino TX (Pin 3)
5VT     - Connect to Arduino RX (Pin 2)
```

Details [**Here**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/44981/26037)